# xml to R dataframe different levels

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I have this xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<sct type="detail" version="0.1">
-<serviceLevelSegments timestamp="2017-10-25T11:45:44Z">
<Segment travelTimeMinutes="0.387" c-value="100" score="30" reference="85" 
average="77" speed="95" code="447332188"/>
-<Segment travelTimeMinutes="0.597" c-value="100" score="30" reference="85" 
average="77" speed="85" code="447332203">
<SubSegment speed="95" PkEnd="782.112" PkIni="781.9" offset="0,212"/>
<SubSegment speed="77" PkEnd="782.746" offset="635,846" pkIni="782.535"/>
</Segment>
</serviceLevelSegments>
</sct>
```

And I want to obtain a table with all attributes (of all the levels). It would be like this:

```
                         Value1      Value2     Value3     ...
timestamp
code
travelTimeMinutes
c-value
score
reference
average
speed (from Segment)
speed (from SubSegment)
PkEnd
PkIni
offset
```

If some cell is empty, I want to put inside: "NA".

I only have found the way to obtain a sepparate table to each level (serviceLevelSegments, Segment or SubSegment by sepparate). For example, to obtain a table for the SubSegment level I have found this code:

```
library(XML)
arch = "file.xml" #code in xml
input <- xmlParse(arch)
nodes <- getNodeSet(input,"//SubSegment")
all_parameters <- sapply(nodes, xmlAttrs)
all_parameters
```

But I obtain a table only with this attributes: speed, offset, PkIni, PkEnd. And I need all the attributes.

Thanks in advance.